# Connection is not avaliable sometimes but app shows that it exists

Tags: android

I have an application which uses the internet. Before send a request I check a connection with code:

```
  protected boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = 
            (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean result = false;
    if (null != activeNetwork) {
        result = activeNetwork.isAvailable() 
            && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }
    return result;
}
```

It works well but in some rare cases logs tell me that app can't execute request because isNetworkAvailable returns false. It was OK until user reasured me that wifi was turned on and he was able to send and receive emails. So do you have any ideas why this kind of situation is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue, if i have airplane mode turned on, no cell/wifi and i run my app it will try not show me the network connection alert, instead it tried to login and then triggers an alert that my server is not reachable.

Here's the original code:

```
    private void CheckNetworkState(Context context)
        {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            boolean error = true;
            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if(activeNetwork != null)
                if(activeNetwork.isConnected()&&activeNetwork.isAvailable())
                    error = false;

            if(error)
                ShowFatalAlert(context,"Internet Connection","This application requires an active internet connection to work!");

            new CheckLogin().execute();
        }

    private void ShowFatalAlert(Context context, String title, String msg){
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        final AlertDialog ad = alert.create();
        alert.setTitle(title);
        alert.setMessage(msg);

        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                MainActivity.this.moveTaskToBack(true);
                //android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            }
        });

        alert.show();
        if(ad.isShowing())
            ad.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestart(){
        super.onRestart();
        if(user.get(1)== "")
            CheckNetworkState(this);
    }
```

the issue i was having is that checklogin is an asynctask and was not waiting for my ShowFatalAlert function to finish.
the solution was as simple as moving the async execute within an else statement:

```
        if(error)
            ShowFatalAlert(context,"Internet Connection","This application requires an active internet connection to work!");
        else            
            new CheckLogin().execute();
```

Not sure how applicable this would be to your code, maybe if you posted the code that calls isNetworkAvailable? Because i don't think you have an issue with this function but with how you are handling it's return.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. My issue lays in another area, befor run request I check my connection state, so this is not an issue with async request like you faced with